# Cesium and Geoserver SRS Optimization

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, cesium, optimization

I have a Cesium program that makes WMS calls to geoserver layers loaded from a postgis table. From what I know Cesium can only use ESPG:4326, but my postgis table and thus geoserver layer are in ESPG:32146. Everything works fine as I'm assuming geoserver converts the SRS to 4326 before passing to Cesium but it isn't super fast. Would my Cesium program would run faster if I converted my geometry column to 4326 in my postgis table so geoserver doesn't have to do the conversion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would my Cesium program would run faster if I converted my geometry column to 4326 in my postgis table so geoserver doesn't have to do the conversion?

So your question is would your Cesium program run faster if you didn't have to reproject in run time, but did it once and stored in that format? Reprojecting is usually pretty cheap, but it's not free. See about storing in 4326, see the geography type and how well it works Cesium.

Yes.